# Animated loader like Snapchat

Tags: objective-c, animation

I was wonder how snapchat animates that ghost thing when you pull down to refresh? I wanted to implement that in my app and was wondering how it was done.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is just a regular pull to refresh, stretching the ghost, then doing a custom animation. This is the closest thing I could find to it. https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/spiralpulltorefresh

Comment: I've been looking all over for a way to use Core Animation with UIRefreshControl, or information on how to make a pull-to-refresh from scratch so I could add animations. Just saw Snapchat's animated refresher, so its totally possible. I'm putting a bounty on this.

Comment: Whoever downvoted- please explain what rules or protocols are being infringed.

Answer (score 7):

I think you need to write your own solution. But it is really not that hard.

You need to create a custom table header view containing a stretchable image and implement some handling in your `UITableViewDelegate`. Below are a fairly generic implementation of a custom refresh control handling.

**1) create a custom UIView to serve as your pulldown indicator view:**

Header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

typedef enum UpdateListViewState
{
    UpdateListViewStatePull,
    UpdateListViewStateRelease,
    UpdateListViewStateUpdate

}UpdateListViewState;


@interface UpdateListView : UIView
@property (nonatomic,readwrite) UpdateListViewState state;
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIImageView imageView;
@end
```

**2) assign the headerView as the tableView header:**

```
self.header = [[UpdateListView alloc] init];
self.table.tableHeaderView = self.header;
```

**3) In your `UITableViewDelegate`, implement table scroll handling:**

```
const int UPDATE_DRAG_HEIGHT = -70; 

- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset 
{
    if (self.header.state == UpdateListViewStateRelease) {
       //Perform update stuff here & perhaps refresh animation
       self.header.state = UpdateListViewStateInitial;

    }
}

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    //adjust size of self.header.imageView here according to scrollView.ContentOffset
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < UPDATE_DRAG_HEIGHT && self.header.state != UpdateListViewStateUpdate) {
            self.header.state = UpdateListViewStateRelease;
    }
}
```